# Work with equation involving different independent variables

Tags: equation-solving

Sometimes I will use an equation, for example, imagine the old chemistry ideal gas law, PV=nRT. Depending on the situation I may want to use different variables as the independent variable. So, for example, in the case of the ideal gas law there are 4 different possible independent variables.

What is a good way to manage this situation and set it up in Mathematica so I can easily compute any particular variable in terms of the others in a literate way?

Comment: `V /. Solve[P V == n R T, V][[1]]`?

Comment: @Feyre I know I can repetitively solve the same equation over and over again. I am hoping there is a more elegant solution.

Comment: What *kind* of thing do you want?

Comment: It is not quite clear what you're asking. Please elaborate by a specific example. In the meanwhile I'm voting to close this question.

Answer (score 2):

```
ClearAll[gasLaw];

gasLaw[var_Symbol, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Solve[P V == n R T, var, Reals, 
   FilterRules[{opts}, Options[Solve]]][[1]]

gasLaw[P]

(*  {P -> (n R T)/V}  *)

Flatten[gasLaw /@ Variables[Level[P V == n R T, {-1}]]]

(*  {n -> (P V)/(R T), P -> (n R T)/V, R -> (P V)/(n T), T -> (P V)/(n R),
  V -> (n R T)/P}  *)
```

Comment: What is `opts : OptionsPattern[]` and `FilterRules[]` doing in this?

Comment: @Sterling - If you evaluate `Options[Solve]` you will see that `Solve` can accept several options. This code enables `gasLaw` to accept these options and pass them to `Solve`. Not very important for this specific equation, but is useful as a general template.

Comment: Ah, great! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this ?

```
var = n;
Solve[P V == n R T, var]
```