# Working with tables of equations in different units

Tags: dynamic, list-manipulation, units

I frequently work with tables of engineering equations in different units. I suppose physicists might do the same thing. For example, a table might look like this:

[image]

Some of the values are inputs and others are computed from the inputs. I put them in spreadsheets with each column representing a different set of units, as you can see. In some cases I copy a formula from one column to the other. Other times, I will convert the value in one column to the other column using a unit conversion.

How can I do something like this in Mathematica? Ideally I would like the input values to be easily editable.

**The Dream**

What would be really cool is if any of the values could be edited and the other values would compute correctly. When I use a spreadsheet, this is impossible. I either have to make the cell contain a number (an independent value), or a formula (a dependent value). Usually, I color the inputs blue. If I could make it so that any cell could be edited and all the others would solve and update correctly, that would be very cool.

Comment: Have you tried anything at all yourself?  Isn't this question essentially a duplicate of [your previous question from today](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/135764/work-with-equation-involving-different-independent-variables)?

Comment: @MarcoB No, the previous question has nothing to do with organization of information and inputs and units. It is just about working with equalities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want something like this.  I use [`InputField`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InputField.html) expressions with `Dynamic` values, and the second parameter of [`Dynamic`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dynamic.html) to update Symbols.

```
tF = tC = -40;

TableForm[{InputField[Dynamic[tC, (tC = #; tF = 9/5 # + 32) &]], 
  InputField[Dynamic[tF, (tF = #; tC = 5/9 (# - 32)) &]]}, 
 TableHeadings -> {{"Celsius", "Fahrenheit"}}]
```

[image]

---

### Metaprogramming

From your comment below I take it that this behavior *is* what you want, but you seek an easy way to extend this to larger tables.  Here is one approach to that.  My function (`toFields`) takes a `List` of related equations, each with a single Symbol on the left-hand side which will become the field variable.  These Symbols must be unassigned (cleared) at that time.  The output is a list of InputFields as shown above, which may then be used in a [`Row`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Row.html), [`Grid`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Grid.html), [`TableForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TableForm.html), etc. as desired.

**Basic example**

```
Clear[tC, tF, tK]

toFields[
  {tC == 5/9 (tF - 32), tF == 9/5 tC + 32, tK == tC + 273 + 3/20}
] // Column
```

[image]

**A complete table**

```
Clear[tC, tF, tK, ft, in, cm]

eq = {
   {tC == 5/9 (tF - 32), tF == 9/5 tC + 32, tK == tC + 273 + 3/20},
   {ft == in/12, in == cm 50/127, cm == 127/50 in}
   };

labels = {{"Celsius", "Fahrenheit", "Kelvin"},
          {"foot", "inch", "centimeter"}};

Grid[
  MapThread[Riffle, {toFields[FieldSize -> 5] /@ eq, labels}]
  , Alignment -> Left
]
```

[image]

#### Function code

```
toDynamic[s_][expr : _Equal | _And] := 
  Dynamic[s, (s = #; expr) & /. {Equal -> Set, And -> CompoundExpression}]

toFields[opts : OptionsPattern[InputField]][rel_] := toFields[rel, opts]

toFields[rel : {(_Symbol == _) ..}, opts___] := 
  With[{var = rel[[All, 1]]}, 
    InputField[#, opts] & @ toDynamic[#]@Reduce[rel, DeleteCases[var, #]] & /@ var
  ]
```

Comment: That definitely seems like the right idea, except I generally have 10 to 20 quantities along the vertical axis and then 2 to 4 different columns each with a different unit system (or scale)

Comment: @TylerDurden This method should work for that case I think.  I guess the issue is programmatically generating this so you don't have to manually type it all in?

Comment: The main thing I am trying to accomplish is the spreadsheet functionality shown in the question. I tried your complete table example in Mathematica 9 but it did not evaluate. Does it have a 10/11 function?

Comment: @Tyler You first loaded the **Function code** shown at the bottom of my answer?  I made a change to it; please be sure you are using the current version.

Comment: It works, that is really cool. It need to play around with the formatting and layout, but I think this is a good solution.

Comment: @TylerDurden I am glad I could help.  Let me know if you have any problems with it.  Thanks for the Accept.